# Area & Perimeter Output Are the Same

Tags: c#, class, overriding, abstract

```
public class Circle : Shape
{
    private float perimeter, area;

    public override float getPerimeter(float Dimension)
    {
        perimeter = (float)(2 * Math.PI) * (Dimension / 2);
        return perimeter;
    }

    public override float getArea(float Dimension)
    {
        area = (float)Math.PI * ((Dimension / 2) * (Dimension / 2));
        return area;
    }

}

public class Square : Shape
{
    private float perimeter, area;

    public override float getPerimeter(float Dimension)
    {
        perimeter = (float)(Dimension * 4);
        return perimeter;
    }

    public override float getArea(float Dimension)
    {
        area = (float)(Dimension * Dimension);
        return area;
    }

}
```

This is only the abstract class but there seems to be a problem here when run the program: the Area and Perimeter output are both the same, and I don't know why.

Comment: whats the input  for which you get same output?

Comment: I don't see any issue with your code. https://dotnetfiddle.net/d6QAsP

Comment: Input 50 Square and get 200 Area, 200 Boundary. Same for Circle if inputted 50 I get 157.09 Area 157.09 Boundary, I know the equation isn't write. Thanks

Comment: @ColinO'Croidheagain did you take a look the code I pointed?

Comment: Looks perfect to me see

https://ideone.com/yinCVQ

Comment: There must be a problem with your code that is called the getPerimeter and getArea. Maybe you are calling the getPerimeter twice by mistake, or outputting the same variable twice.